# Hollow Deadbolt

Tags: doors, lock

I was looking at a door look recently and noticed the deadbolt had a hole through it so that it was hollow (the hole was only .5 inches wide or so). Also there appeared to be a plastic plug in the hole. To be clear the hole appears to be drilled in the direction of the screws holding the contact plate on and not perpendicular.

I searched around the web a bit, but I kept finding results about hollow core doors which is not related to the question.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deadbolts sometimes do have a hole along the long axis of the bolt. Into this hole is fitted a hardened steel rod that can turn inside the hole. The objective of this is that if someone tries to stick a hack saw blade through the door crack in an attempt to saw off the deadbolt it will only cut into the depth of that rod. As the saw teeth try to engage the steel rod it will only roll back and forth instead of allowing itself to get cut off.

It is possible that some cheaper deadbolts use a high density plastic rod in place of the hardened steel one.

Comment: More likely the plastic plug is a bearing to permit the hardened rod to spin more easily, and thus be more effective.

Comment: Based on what I was able to see, the rod itself was plastic, my description as a plug was probably not correct, but it doesn't seem to be acting as a bearing. I am accepting the answer as I believe this to be the situation. Thank you.